# How do I poll for a file within a single threaded blocking code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code

```
main():
    fn1()#<= fn1 would generate a large file
    if mysize(some_file_generated_by_fn1) > 1GB:
        fn2()
```

Now I am looking to terminate fn1() and return as soon as the file generated becomes more than 1GB and not wait for the full file to be generated. How shhould I do that ?

Comment: You can get the size of a file by using [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)—it's `st_size`. You can "poll" this value by calling `time.sleep()` between successive `stat()` calls.

Comment: `size(some_file_generated_by_fn1)` code has `os.stat()`. Please write the full working code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about single threaded, another thread would be needed in order to execute `fn1()` and do file-size polling concurrently—so I don't think it can be done. What do you have against using multiple threads?

Comment: is it possible to modify `fn1()` ?

Comment: fn1() is an external process call which generates the file